# How to make a double 'continue' in a loop?

Tags: python

Is it possible to make a double continue and jump to the item after the next item in the list in python?

Comment: Consume an item off the list (and forget it), then continue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an iterator:

```
>>> list_iter = iter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> for i in list_iter:
...     print "not skipped: ", i
...     if i == 3:
...         print "skipped: ", next(list_iter, None)
...         continue
... 
not skipped:  1
not skipped:  2
not skipped:  3
skipped:  4
not skipped:  5
```

Using the `next` builtin with a default of `None` avoids raising `StopIteration` -- thanks kevpie for the suggestion!

Comment: not sure what your comment means?  You need to use the iter object so you can advance it with next().  You can use the builtin _next(iterator[, default])_ to advance it it without raising StopIteration.  `next(list_iter, None)` will return None instead.

Comment: A default must be provided to avoid the exception being raised. next(list_iter, **None**)

Answer (score 10):

Not really, but you can use a variable telling it to `continue` again after the first continue:

```
continue_again = False
for thing in things:
    if continue_again:
        continue_again = False
        continue
    # ...
    if some_condition:
        # ...
        continue_again = True
        continue
    # ...
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you just increment the iterator?

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    i = i + 1
    continue
```